# Connecting to multiple servers using axios keep alive

Tags: axios, keep-alive

I'm refactoring a server that pulls information from several different APIs to use a keep-alive connection. The only [example](https://dev.to/melitus/comment/10cbj) I've seen that uses keep alive with axios uses a single axios instance with an agent that has keep alive set to true. If I'm connecting to multiple api's, that are all run on different servers, can I use a single axios instance or would I have to create an instance for each server that I connect to?

Comment: It will be good if you create axios instance per server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considerable testing (we set up a server to connect to several host simultaneously and let it run for a bit) it looks like you only need a single axios instance and a single agent to handle any number of hosts. As a side note, the [agentkeepalive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agentkeepalive) package is a good agent to use because it handles cleaning up sockets that the [https agent](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_class_https_agent) package doesn't